# How to have byte array data produced by RabbitMQ Kafka connector get a key?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect

I use the official Kafka RabbitMQ connector to get JSOn messages from a RabbitMQ instance.

Currently, this connector if configured like this

```
name=RabbitMQConsentConsumer
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector
rabbitmq.host=HOST
rabbitmq.port=PORT
rabbitmq.username=USER
rabbitmq.password=PASSWORD
rabbitmq.virtual.host=vhost
tasks.max=1
kafka.topic=TOPIC
rabbitmq.queue=QUEUE
errors.log.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Using that configuration, I can have my JSON messages injected as byte array into Kafka, and recognized by readers as JSON content. This is "quite" good.

But I would like to generate keys from JSON content in Kafka Connect.
For that, I want to use transformers.

So I've started to play with transformers ... And I've added the following configuration

```
transforms=MakeMap
transforms.MakeMap.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value
transforms.MakeMap.fields=jsonEvent
```

Unfortunatly, it fails with the following message

```
[2019-04-25 08:04:25,128] ERROR Error encountered in task RabbitMQConsentConsumer-0. Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter', where source record is = SourceRecord{sourcePartition={routingKey=TOPIC}, sourceOffset={deliveryTag=1}} ConnectRecord{topic='TOPIC', kafkaPartition=null, key=null, keySchema=Schema{STRING}, value=[B@20a106a8, valueSchema=Schema{BYTES}, timestamp=1556179465126, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=[ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.consumer.tag, value=amq.ctag-7PHmHnIJF2WCnxJShauM3A, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.content.type, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.content.encoding, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.delivery.mode, value=1, schema=Schema{INT32}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.priority, value=0, schema=Schema{INT32}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.correlation.id, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.reply.to, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.expiration, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.message.id, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.timestamp, value=null, schema=Schema{org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp:INT64}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.type, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.user.id, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.app.id, value=null, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.delivery.tag, value=1, schema=Schema{INT64}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.redeliver, value=false, schema=Schema{BOOLEAN}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.exchange, value=, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=rabbitmq.routing.key, value=TOPIC, schema=Schema{STRING})])}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid schema type for ByteArrayConverter: STRUCT
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter.fromConnectData(ByteArrayConverter.java:55)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:269)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:269)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:293)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:228)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-04-25 08:04:25,128] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=RabbitMQConsentConsumer-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2019-04-25 08:04:25,128] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=RabbitMQConsentConsumer-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2019-04-25 08:04:25,128] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=RabbitMQConsentConsumer-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:269)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:293)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:228)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid schema type for ByteArrayConverter: STRUCT
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter.fromConnectData(ByteArrayConverter.java:55)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:269)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
  ... 11 more
[2019-04-25 08:04:25,129] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=RabbitMQConsentConsumer-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

From what I understand, it seems like my `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value` transform fails because my data is a Byte Array, and not a Struct/Map. Considering that, ho can I "upgrade" my message from byte array to json ?

Comment: why not just use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` ?

Comment: Can you please confirm, Is this connector as expected if you dont use transform in your connector configuration.?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Seems like the RabbitMQ connector value schema imposes value to be a bytes array (see in `com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.MessageConverter.SCHEMA_VALUE`) : from what i understand, the line `.field(FIELD_MESSAGE_BODY, SchemaBuilder.bytes().doc("The value body (opaque, client-specific byte array)").build())` seems to force message value to be a byte array which (as far as I understand) doesn't seems to be processable with Kafka connect transformers

Comment: @GokulPotluri YES, if I use the configuration from the first property block as is, the messages are correctly sent to Kafka broker.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the code. But, have you tried `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` and got an error?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt If i use the JsonCovnerter, messages are output in Kafka broker as Base64 encoded ... which is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

The data pipeline for connectors is, first the data is retrieved from source, apply transform on it and apply provided converters in top of that transformed data and then push it into provided topic.

Now here in your case,  data might be coming in bytearray by after applying transform on that data, it is getting converted to struct type which is not supported by bytearray format. So, you are getting that exception.

HostField is meant for wrapping data into STRUCT format when there is schema provided for source data.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/hoistfield.html#hoistfield

As @Robin Moffatt said, Please try using JSON converter and try, it should work.